# Transformation using Linux

Tags: transformation

Using Linux (Bash), I would like to transform a file such that 1 = A A; 2 = B B; 3 = C C and 0 = 0 0:

input file:

```
1210
2312
1201
```

Output fiel:

```
A A B B A A 0 0
B B C C A A B B
A A B B 0 0 A A
```

I have tried this one, but did not result in what I want:

cat file | tr [1230] [A A B B C C 0 0]

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
cat << EOF | sed 's/0/0 0 /g;s/1/A A /g;s/2/B B /g;s/3/C C /g;s/ $//g'
1210
2312
1201
EOF
```

Which outputs:

```
A A B B A A 0 0
B B C C A A B B
A A B B 0 0 A A
```

There may be more elegant ways. This one is using `sed` with multiple commands to perform the 4 substitutions (including a suffix space separator), and a final command to trim the last trailing space at the end of the line, if present after all the substitutions have been made.

See also:

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed
- https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax

Comment: Thanks! Partially, it did what I want, but I am not sure why it leaves one line empty between lines if I send the results to a file:                           cat test.txt | sed 's/0/0 0/g;s/1/A A/g;s/2/B B/g;s/3/C C/g;s/$//g'>f

Comment: Make sure to include all the spaces in the sed commands. You're not testing the exact thing I posted :)